# Adding scrollbar to horizontal view

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

By debugging this web interface, I found an issue about the horizontal view, as you can see in the image below, for horizontal view it need more vertical space, so it need to add a scrollbar, in my case between header and footer, like the old html frame concept. But the scrollbar don't appear, so the form is cutted. how can  I fix it?
Also trying to resize it on desktop by following the [LINK](https://unknow.tv/prova6.php) is without scrollbar.
[image: Current]

Answer (score 0):

You are using `position: fixed`. `fixed` and `absolute` both 'remove' the element from its parent, it thus no longer contributes to the height of the body. In my opinion the easiest would be to create a container with a flexbox and center the card that way.